# Extract only Hour from Epochtime in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a dataframe with one of its column as epochtime. 
I want to extract only hour from it and display it as a separate column.

Below is the sample dataframe:

```
+----------+-------------+
|    NUM_ID|        STIME|
+----------+-------------+
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634285000|
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634299000|
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634311000|
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634316000|
|xxxxxxxx02|1571634318000|
|xxxxxxxx02|1571398176000|
|xxxxxxxx02|1571627596000|
```

Below is the expected output.

```
+----------+-------------+-----+
|    NUM_ID|        STIME| HOUR|
+----------+-------------+-----+
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634285000|  10 |
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634299000|  10 |
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634311000|  10 |
|xxxxxxxx01|1571634316000|  10 |
|xxxxxxxx02|1571634318000|  10 |
|xxxxxxxx02|1571398176000|  16 |
|xxxxxxxx02|1571627596000|  08 |
```

I have tried

```
val test = test1DF.withColumn("TIME", extract HOUR(from_unixtime($"STIME"/1000)))
```

which throws exception at

```
<console>:46: error: not found: value extract
```

Tried as below to obtain date format and even it is not working.

```
val test = test1DF.withColumn("TIME", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("STIME")))
```

The datatype of STIME in dataframe is Long.

Any leads to extract hour from epochtime in Long datatype?

Comment: it worked with ```val test = test1DF.withColumn("TIME", hour(from_unixtime($"STIME"/1000)))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the hours from a timestamp is as simple as using the [`hour()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@hour(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df_with_hour = df.withColumn("TIME", hour(from_unixtime($"STIME" / 1000)))

df_with_hour.show()
// +-------------+----+
// |        STIME|TIME|
// +-------------+----+
// |1571634285000|   5|
// |1571398176000|  11|
// |1571627596000|   3|
// +-------------+----+
```

(Note: I'm in a different timezone)